# Как открыть адрес вида xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx через Selenium?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Ну в целом весь вопрос в заголовке, при попытке сделать через get, открывается пустая страница

Comment: Установили ли вы путь к вебдрайверу и является ли url валидным?

Comment: `http://` / `https://` стоит в адресе? Просто 192.168.1.1 не будет работать.

Comment: 2 часа бился, не мог понять, как же я тупанул, спасибо тебе большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы открыть адрес с протоколом IPv6 с помощью Selenium, вы можете использовать метод get() драйвера Selenium, указав полный URL-адрес, включая протокол 'http://' или 'https://', например:

```
driver.get('http://[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]')
```

Обратите внимание, что квадратные скобки вокруг адреса IPv6 обязательны, так как они обозначают, что это адрес IPv6, а не доменное имя.

Если вы используете протокол HTTPS, не забудьте установить соответствующий сертификат, если требуется. В противном случае вы можете столкнуться с ошибками сертификата SSL.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку!