# Почему при запросе selenium выдаёт пустую страницу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-2.x

Почему когда я просто открываю сайт через selenium он выдаёт пустую страницу?
Вот код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://myvisit.com/#!/home/signin/")

sleep(1000)
```

Почему так происходит? Перерыл весь интернет, но ничего дельного не нашёл.
[image: Вот так выглядит сама страница]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как открыть адрес вида xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx через Selenium?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474306/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-selenium)

Comment: Nowhere Man, там говорится про запрос на численный адрес, и в том вопросе проблема была в том, что автор не указал http:// в начале адреса. У меня же всё указано, но всё равно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего стоит защита от вебдрайвера, даже не, скорее всего, а так и есть.
Нам понадобится Firefox, в нем настройки не ограничены.

```
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
option.set_preference('dom.webdriver.enabled', False) 

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option)
driver.get('https://myvisit.com/#!/home/signin/')
```

Пробуйте, мы отключили "webdriver", должно сработать....

Comment: Нет, не отключили. С версии фф 88 этот флаг ничего не выключает.